# Mysterious EOFError in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on my first Rails 4 app when all of a sudden I started getting this mysterious EOFError.  Checked out some old commits via git when everything was working fine and the error was still there.

```
EOFError in Labels#index
Extracted source (around line #5):

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I figured out a workaround, which is to rename application.css to app.css and change to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "app", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

but still no idea why this is happening.  Any thoughts?

Comment: :data-turbolinks-track=>true ?

Comment: We had today the same problem because... we had css file named `global.css`. We use bootstrap-rails, sass-rails and less-rails, I don't know what exactly causes this problem. After renaming this file it works just fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Clear your sprockets cache

```
rm tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/*
```

Comment: There was an error in some asset, and for some arcane reason that generated an invalid cached asset, which caused EOF when rails tried to read it.

Comment: My sprockets directory was empty so I cleared out the entire tmp/cache directory (probably could have just done assets) and it fixed it.